# What exactly did Donald Trump say about abortion?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, abortion

Many news reports say that in an interview with Chris Matthews in March 2016, Donald Trump said that women who have abortions should be punished.

What exactly did he say?

Comment: Of course, a decade ago he was "Very pro-choice", but then, he wasn't catering to a certain portion of the electorate back then. I wonder if he even knows his real opinions on things sometimes.... http://www.nbcnews.com/meet-the-press/video/trump-in-1999-i-am-very-pro-choice-480297539914

Comment: Any question of the form "What exactly did XXX politician say" has to be prefaced with exact timeframe. Extra so for Trump.

Comment: This isn't hard to look up on your own. I'm not even sure this is on topic here.

Comment: @user4012 should this be in the title or in the question details?

Comment: @user1605665 - details is better I think

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [Full Transcript](http://info.msnbc.com/_news/2016/03/30/35330907-full-transcript-msnbc-town-hall-with-donald-trump-moderated-by-chris-matthews?lite) is available from MSNBC.

> MATTHEWS:  Do you believe in punishment for abortion, yes or no as a principle?
>
> TRUMP:  The answer is that there has to be some form of punishment.
>
> MATTHEWS:  For the woman?
>
> TRUMP:  Yes, there has to be some form.
>
> MATTHEWS:  Ten cents?  Ten years?  What?
>
> TRUMP:  Let me just tell you -- I don't know.  That I don't know.  That I don't know.

Trump later clarified his remarks in [an official statement](https://www.donaldjtrump.com/press-releases/donald-j.-trump-statement-regarding-abortion).

> **​DONALD J. TRUMP STATEMENT REGARDING ABORTION**
>
> If Congress were to pass legislation making abortion illegal and the federal courts upheld this legislation, or any state were permitted to ban abortion under state and federal law, the doctor or any other person performing this illegal act upon a woman would be held legally responsible, not the woman. The woman is a victim in this case as is the life in her womb. My position has not changed - like Ronald Reagan, I am pro-life with exceptions.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37798/discussion-on-answer-by-user1873-what-exactly-did-donald-trump-say-about-abortio).